# Unable to view Model with OBJLoader React Three Fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to render an .obj file into my react project using the OBJLoader and useLoader() hook from React Three Fiber, but I'm unable to do so. My file path is correct and I'm wrapping the Model in Suspense tags, so why is this occurring?

```js
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { Canvas, useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { OBJLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader";

function Model() {
    const model = useLoader(
        OBJLoader,
        "../assets/Model.obj"
    );

    return <primitive object={model} scale={0.4} />;
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Canvas>
                <OrbitControls
                    enablePan={true}
                    enableZoom={true}
                    enableRotate={true}
                    addEventListener={undefined}
                    hasEventListener={undefined}
                    removeEventListener={undefined}
                    dispatchEvent={undefined}
                />
                <Lights />
                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                    <Model />
                </Suspense>
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your 3D files inside the public folder.
Then your path will be   "./Model.obj"
Also you can make make folders inside public folder and put 3D models inside them.
ex- "./folder1/Model.obj"  like this